# How do you show a derivation of a string using a grammar?

Tags: parsing, grammar

I am a little confused on how to show a derivation of something given a grammar. For example, I need to show a derivation of ((())) using a grammar and starting with S. This is the grammar: S = () | (S). Here is what my solution looks like so far, S -> () -> (()) -> ((())). I feel like this is completely wrong, so any explanation would help me out tremendously. I am new to this topic.

Comment: Show the sequence of symbols and what production you're applying at each step. There's no production that would take you from `()` to `(())` or from there to `((()))`.

Answer (score 1):

You can't derive anything from (). If you want to continue beyond the first step there needs to be a nonterminal symbol in there. Your only nonterminal symbol is S.

Comment: So it isn't possible to show a derivation of ((())) from the grammar: S = () | (S) ?

Comment: It is possible. Considering that you can't derive it from (), what's your other possibility?

Comment: (S) is the other possibility. So I would start like this: S -> (S) -> ((S)) -> then what? Maybe this, S -> (S) -> ((S)) -> ((()))

Comment: Thank you, thank you for the help. What are the steps of derivation?

Comment: Informally I would say that each of your arrows "->" is a step. You can check whether whatever resources you have provide a formal definition of "steps of derivation."

(Sort of interesting? Some writers use "->" followed by a star "*" to mean that there is a derivation -- that the left-hand side produces the right-hand side by one or more steps.)